# Рожа - лицо и рожа - болезнь

Tags: этимология

Рожей называют лицо с негативным или пренебрежительным оттенком. Либо так называют всевозможные гримасы - "состроить рожу". Но при этом есть болезнь - рожистое воспаление, когда вокруг инфицированной раны начинается сепсис.
Как я понимаю, слово "рожа" происходит от слова "рог" (или ошибаюсь?), но какая связь? Еще с болезнью я могу понять - пораженные ткани могут ороговеть. А вот как быть с гримасой, почему она - рожа?

Answer (score 1):

Рожа - слово русского происхождения; рожистый - французского (от rouge - красный; связано с синдромом покраснения).

Answer (score 1):

1. Рожа в значении *лицо* происходит от древнерусского **рожай** (ср. : *урожай*), слова с несколькими значениями, одно из которых - *внешность, облик, лицо*.

   > [Посол] привезъ къ шаху дѣвку... а **рожаемъ** де она непомѣрно красна (источник 1599).
2. Рожа = роза, от польского **róża**.
3. Рожа - болезнь, воспаление; название восходит ко второму значению, от красного цвета кожи.

   > Сѣла патриарху рожа на рожу (1691).

(Использованы данные СлРЯ 11-17 вв)